# What are all the places an IP address can be set on a ubuntu 16.04+ default installation?

Tags: ubuntu, ip

I just tried to change my servers IP as 'ip address show' displays 192.168.1.8 which conflicts with another system.

Netplan is not installed.
The router is not feeding it a static IP

The /etc/network/interfaces file was configured as DHCP so I changed it to 192.168.1.30

Now it is showing both
192.168.1.8
192.168.1.30

[image]
[image]

Im sick of going through this every time so please for both myself and everyone else who goes through this as often as I do, what are all the places that you can set an IP address?

Comment: Is your DHCP server handing out duplicated IP addresses? It would be better to try to figure out what enabled your DHCP server to give two systems the same address, or in what other way that other system got an address in the DHCP range, than to set a static address that may later be assign to another system from the DHCP server.

Comment: There's netplan (in turn using systemd-networkd, probably)

Comment: @Kusalananda I initially did think of that however after removing the DHCP setting from the interfaces file and issuing 'sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart', it should no longer have 192.168.1.8 unless its getting it locally.

Comment: @muru Yes that is another valid place however I did check the /etc/systemd but its not coming from there. Also, netplan is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... set your system etc files for ubuntu back to non-static or the original before anything was changed. Then put your router in DHCP mode. Restart both. Check your ip address and see what dhcp assigns your computer. Also scan your entire network of devices for conflicts. I use angry ip scanner ( I just like GUIs). From that point on it should work. You can then re-assign another static IP.

Comment: Im not sure that would do anything but you did give me an idea of how to find out if it's getting assigned locally or by DHCP. I changed the range in the router to start at 192.168.1.100. If it's a leased IP then it will now be greater than 100, if it's a local static one in a mystical file somewhere in the dredges of the OS, then it will not change.

I am currently initializing a raid 5 on that server though so wont be able to check for a while. I'll check back with the results.

Comment: After a reboot of the server, the 192.168.1.8 address is gone. Not sure why 'sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart' and the up/down commands did not clear it out. Will leave as unanswered so people can post answers to the posted question other 'What are all the places an IP address can be set on a ubuntu 16.04+ default installation?'. Perhaps someone will come up with some sort of unified list and if it's agreed by others that should be the answer, then I will select that one. I don't mind if you include network places such as router, it might help others in a similar situation.

Comment: When it comes to routers, all of them are a little different when it comes to way it handles ip address. Question unrelated to the ip issue. Why are you using RAID 5 instead 10?

Comment: The server came as vd0 drive 0, vd1, drives 1-3 as raid 0. I did not know much about server architecture at the time and so installed the OS on sda thinking it would naturally be one large vd. Now I figure if the OS is on sda, its file access wont be slowing down data access on sdb. Had I known at the time, I would definitely put the OS on an external drive and used raid 10.